# LoadRunner - Siebel - Session warning message while replaying the script

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, siebel, vugen

I am playing around with LoadRunner to performance test a Sielbel CRM application. The protocol ( Siebel web) is selected before the run and also the .cor file is associated using the recording options dialog.

I have also copied the DLL ssdtcorr.dll to the bin folder. All is good and I am able to record the scripts.
While replaying the script, I am getting the below screen

[image]

Not sure what is the issue here...

I have gone through the script and observed that timestamp ,Siebel_SWECount , SiebelTimeStamp ,Siebel_SWEACn and Siebel_SWEVLC are  correlated automatically.

Is there any other params which needs to be correlated.

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help

PS: My application is a single session setup. It means, I cannot login simultaneously with the same credentials more than once in a given time. The later login will give a session warning message.

But while replaying the script, I made sure that there is no active session with the credential I am using with the script.

**UPDATE 1**

The below code is what is causing the issue

```
web_submit_data("start.swe_14", 
    "Action=http://XX.YYY.ZZZ.AA/SSS/start.swe", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=http://XX.YYY.ZZZ.AA/SSS/start.swe?SWECmd=Login&SWEPL=1&SRN=&SWETS={SiebelTimeStamp}", 
    "Snapshot=t17.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    "EncodeAtSign=YES", 
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=SWECmd", "Value=InvokeMethod", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEService", "Value=Web Engine Client Preferences", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEMethod", "Value=SetClientCapability", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEIPS", "Value=@0`0`1`0``3``cpf`Mobile=false`", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWERPC", "Value=1", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SRN", "Value=4FeDpVgxP8msdfbfdbbgdTGtzQbkLyoO0spzO8Ywb", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWEC", "Value={Siebel_SWECount}", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWETS", "Value={SiebelTimeStamp}", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);
```

The reason for the failure is that the SRN value is hardcoded and is not correlated.

```
"Name=SRN", "Value=4FeDpVgxP8msdfbfdbbgdTGtzQbkLyoO0spzO8Ywb", ENDITEM,
```

Could anyone please help me as how to fetch the SRN value automatically so that I am not using the hard coded SRN value.

SRN is Sesssion Random Number

Any pointers is very much helpful for me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When *automated correlation* fails, use ***manual correlation*** techniques.   Using the same user credentials, record the same business process twice.  Compare the generated code.  It should become obvious what needs to be addressed.  You can add a third recording session tied to a different user ID to validate your observations.

There is also the rule of thumb model.  If you did not type it in or pick it off the screen then you need to look at either a correlated source or a local code generation source.  in this case, SRN, is likely a value you did not type in or pick off the screen.

***Manual correlation*** methods should confirm the dynamic nature of the value.  Standard ***manual correlation*** techniques covered in training and the tutorial before *automated correlation*, should help you to identify the location of the information being sent back so you can add the appropriate ***manual correlation*** statements to capture the value/